# Firemonkey TMemo each line with a different color

Tags: delphi, colors, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, tmemo

Adding lines in a `TMemo` (Firemonkey), each line with a different color?

Note: Firemonkey doesn't have RichEdit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with a TMemo as there is no formatting ability with a TMemo simply a string list.  You will need to find another control to work for you.